# Aplicação .Net perdendo referência

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Boa tarde. Tenho uma aplicação web desenvolvida em c# que utiliza conexão com o banco Mysql. Adicionei a referencia, o codebehind reconhece a referencia ao Mysql sem problemas. Só que ao executar a aplicação, dá o erro : Error
2 The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Desinstalei o conector do mysql, reinstalei e refiz a referencia na aplicação e nada, mesmo erro. Alguem sabe informar o que ocorre?

No aguardo

Comment: não está claro o que você está tentando fazer, o que está tentando instalar....

Comment: Instalar nada, estou tentando referenciar o myslq no meu projeto asp.net. O que eu instalei e que é necessario para tanto é o myslqconnector; Já instalei, fiz a referencia, o codebehind reconhece a referencia, mas na hora de executar o build, dá o erro que nao encontra a referencia com o mysql

Comment: então está tentando instalar o driver de conexão com o mysql. Resta saber qual, quais as dependências, etc...

Comment: Já está instalado Myslq Connector Net 8.0.12. A instalação está ok. O codebehind abre as referencias do Mysql, ( MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand,  MySqlDataAdapter), Só que ao efeturar o Buind, da o erro dizendo que não envontrou a referencia.

Comment: Está copiando as dll do MySQL para a Bin e ou verificou se elas estão disponíveis no GAC?

Comment: Não copiou para a bin

Comment: descobri, era versão do framework no projeto. Essa versão do mysql so roda a partir da versão 4.5.2 e meu projeto estava na 4.5. Mudei a versão e funcionou. O Visual studio não informa esta fincionalidade, verifiquei em outro forum americano.